# How to use Riverpod with CustomPainter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I've been searching around the answer and didn't find much information about how to use Riverpod with CustomPainter.

I got two problems that showed up when I used Riverpod with CustomPainter.

1. (Fixed, please ignore.) I tried to use CustomPainter to draw lines, but CustomPainter won't draw the line after the start point and the end point has changed. (ref.watch not updating immediately)
2. There is a provider I need to update inside CustomPainter, which gave me an error like this: "Modifying a provider inside those life-cycles is not allowed, as it could lead to an inconsistent UI state." (I know I shouldn't update the value inside the build, but I'm curious about how to solve this, especially for CustomPainter or CustomMultiChildLayout.)

```
Consumer(
   builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: EdgePainter(
        ref: ref,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

```
class EdgePainter extends CustomPainter {
  WidgetRef ref;

  EdgePainter({
    required this.ref,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    var node = ref.watch(connectedNodeListProvider);
    var start = ref.watch(startKeyProvider);
    var end = ref.watch(endKeyProvider);
    var cardPositions = ref.watch(cardPositionMapProvider);

    if (node.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var i in node) {
        if (cardPositions[i.$1] != Offset.infinite &&
            cardPositions[i.$2] != Offset.infinite) {
          canvas.drawLine(cardPositions[i.$1]!, cardPositions[i.$2]!, paint);
        }
      }
    }

    if (start != null && end != null) {
      if (cardPositions[start] != Offset.infinite &&
          cardPositions[end] != Offset.infinite) {
        canvas.drawLine(cardPositions[start]!, cardPositions[end]!, paint);
        node.add((start!, end!));
        // var nodeValue = ref.read(connectedNodeListProvider);
        // nodeValue.add((start, end));
        // ref.read(connectedNodeListProvider.notifier).update((state) {
        //   state = nodeValue.toList();
        //   return state;
        // });
        start = null;
        end = null;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I'm new to Riverpod, so please tell me anything I did wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `ref.watch` inside a widget `build` method, consumer `builder` method, or the body of another provider. Move all `ref.watch` to the `Consumer`'s `builder` body and pass the values as arguments to `EdgePainter`:

```dart
Consumer(
   builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
    var node = ref.watch(connectedNodeListProvider);
    var start = ref.watch(startKeyProvider);
    var end = ref.watch(endKeyProvider);
    var cardPositions = ref.watch(cardPositionMapProvider);

    return CustomPaint(
      painter: EdgePainter(
        ref: ref,
        node: node,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        cardPositions: cardPositions,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Make `shouldRepaint` returns `true` if there are changes from those parameters that should trigger the `paint` method.

```dart
@override
bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => start != oldDelegate.start && ... // This is just an example
```

Comment: This is the first approach I tried before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can include your first approach too in the post

Comment: Okay, my bad. After some debugging, I realized there was a bug when I set value to the cardPositionMapProvider. It causes CustomPaint to not draw the line because it doesn't have the offset to begin with. Your answer is correct. Do you have any thoughts on the second problem?